# Como posso criar um streaming a partir de um video que esta no servidor?

Tags: javascript, api, websocket, streaming

Como o próprio titulo já diz, eu preciso criar um streaming ao vivo de um vídeo do servidor, ou do youtube ou algo do tipo, alguém pode me dar uma dica de como posso iniciar?
Pesquisei muito, e em todo lugar que procurei só encontrei ajuda/tutoriais relacionas a lives stream dai já entra parte de webcam e audio... e não esse meu objetivo.
Qualquer link ou ajuda é bem vinda!

Comment: dá uma olhada, é stream de audio e é direto dá maquina do cliente para os demais usuarios do sistema, mas modificando esse sistema dá para alterar para video, mas não é direto do servidor!!! https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/stream-mp3-live.html

Comment: dá uma olhada no site dele tambem: http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/

Comment: pow vou dar uma olhada aqui, valeu cara.

Comment: Talvez eu tenha me expressado de maneira errada, eu tenho um arquivo de vídeo, e quero que esse arquivo seja reproduzido em minha pagina ao vivo, exemplo, coloco as 13h e todo mundo que for acessar vai ver o vídeo sendo reproduzido.
Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Sim você pode!

existe um software que ajuda nisso, e torna o streaming compatível com dispositivos móveis também!!!!

servidor de streaming [wowza] --> http://wowza.com

e você precisará de um cliente de streaming capaz de pegar os dados vindos do servidor (wowza) e colocar em um player que seja amigavel com desktop e mobile:

player [JW Player] --> http://jwplayer.com

abraço!!

Comment: Desculpa, talvez esteja fazendo uma pergunta besta, mas é que sou novo nessa questão streaming e afins. Mas eu posso utilizar estas ferramentas que você citou e testando em um ambiente local? localhost?
Sou estudante e não tenho $$$

Comment: O Wowza você pode usa-lo por 30 dias gratuitos. o jwplayer tem uma versão free! se sua intenção é estudo será ideal

Comment: Agradeço as dicas Aloiso, de fato fiz o cadastro no wowza e consegui a versão free do JW Player, o grande problema é que não consegui utilizar as duas ferramentas em comunhão. Estou recorrendo ao html5 e ao websocket para tentar atingir meu objetivo. Grato pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma activity para abrir o layout com uma `VideoView` e outra para trabalhar com o streaming com um layout próprio também:

```
  private ProgressDialog carregando;
  private Context context;
  private VideoView mVideoView;

      public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
      {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        this.context = this;
        this.carregando = ProgressDialog.show(this.context, "", "Carregando...", true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
        {
          public void onCancel(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface)
          {
            Player.this.carregando.dismiss();
            Player.this.mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            Player.this.mVideoView.setVisibility(8);
          }
        });
        this.carregando.setCancelable(true);
        this.mVideoView = ((VideoView)findViewById(R.layout.videoview));
        this.mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
        {
          public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer paramAnonymousMediaPlayer)
          {
            Player.this.carregando.dismiss();
          }
        });
        this.mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
        {
          public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer paramAnonymousMediaPlayer)
          {
            Player.this.mVideoView.setVisibility(8);
            Player.this.carregando.dismiss();
          }
        });
        this.mVideoView.setVisibility(0);
        this.mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("linkdostreamingnoservidor"));
        MediaController localMediaController = new MediaController(this.context);
        this.mVideoView.setMediaController(localMediaController);
        Log.d("NSLog", "Talvez isso: " + this.context + " ou isso: " + localMediaController);
        this.mVideoView.requestFocus();
        this.mVideoView.start();
      }
```