# Reprodução vídeo ao vivo usando websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, streaming

Gostaria de fazer a transmissão de um vídeo que esta em meu banco de dados (MySQL) e gostaria de saber se é possível reproduzir conteúdo de mídia ao vivo utilizando websocket, e se for como eu poderia construir? Tenho em mente que vou utilizar html5 e JS e uma linguagem back end (php ou até mesmo python). Se alguém puder dar uma dica ou exemplo de como poderia iniciar?

Comment: relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27038/como-posso-criar-um-streaming-a-partir-de-um-video-que-esta-no-servidor

Comment: Desculpe Sergio, mas este link não me ajudou, tem alguma outra dica de como construir?

Comment: Sinceramente eu não implementaria nada em websocket. É possível mais var dar muito trabalho. Tem vários protocolos de streaming que fazem adaptação de banda, real-time e várias outras coisas bem avançadas. Além de que você vai ter de conhecer bem o codec que estará usando e as questões de compressão de vídeo e perdas de pacotes/reorganização de pacotes

Comment: Alexandre, muito obrigado pela dica, mas tu teria alguma dica de como posso solucionar este problema?
Tentei utilizar o wowza mas tive tremenda dificuldade, dai procurei outras alternativas e achei algumas respostas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736116/online-audio-video-conference-system-in-html5#comment5269744_4738065 mas ainda estou confuso de como resolver o problema, estou aberto a dicas, links, qualquer tipo de ajuda é bem vinda.

Comment: @User qual foi a dificuldade ao se utilizar o Wowza? O Wowza funciona realmente muito bem para o propósito que você busca, tanto que alguns serviços da Amazon oferecem o Wowza no pacote. O "grande problema" é a licença.

Comment: Obrigado por participar Adriano, minha dificuldade ao utilizar wowza.
a primeira não é bem dificuldade, mas é bem complicado é a linguagem, outra dificuldade é de entender como utilizar, se é no wowza que eu hospedo o vídeo, sinceramente o wowza pode e deve ser uma ótima ferramenta, mas não encontrei nada que pudesse me dizer o que de fato ele faz.

Comment: Por estes motivos pesquisei outra forma de criar a transmissão ao vivo utilizando websockets, se tiver algum link para me direcionar melhor nesta questão do wowza ou até mesmo do websockets fico muito agradecido. Obrigado Adriano!

Answer (score 2):

[Este blogpost](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17342433#17342433http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets) mostra como fazer streaming de vídeo usando websockets, node.js e o ffmpeg, usando a biblioteca [jsmpeg](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg). O post foca no lado do servidor, mas [a documentação da biblioteca](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg/blob/master/README.md) explica com detalhes os dois lados. Parece ser exatamente o que você está procurando.

[Este tutorial](http://blog.kaazing.com/2014/01/23/extreme-html5-video-interactivity-sending-websocket-messages-with-popcorn-js/) sobre interatividade em vídeo sobre sockets também pode te interessar.

Comment: Bah Geilton, pesquisei bastante, e é por isso que recorri ao stack, mas em nenhuma pesquisa encontrei este primeiro link, o segundo eu já tinha conhecimento, mas muito obrigado, esse primeiro link me parece muito útil, e já estou dando uma olhada no popcorn.js

Comment: @User Na verdade o que está no *segundo* link é exatamente o que você procura.

Answer (score 1):

ola uma boa ideia seria utilizar a tecnologia [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/), é bem facil, eu mesmo ja testei, mais não criei nada grande, mais é possível entregar conteúdo por websocket utilizando nodejs, principalmente se trabalhar com o framework express.js, não posso te dizer como fazer, mais posso contribuir com ideias.

Comment: Show de bola Willian Borba, já estava me familiarizando com o node.js, dei uma lida e vi um pouco sobre streaming, mas tu sabe me dizer se posso transmitir conteúdo ao vivo apenas com o node.js ?

Obrigado por participar!

Comment: o que eu tava fazendo era um chat, mais pra streaming eu não cheguei a fazer, fiz uma busca e achei uns links https://gist.github.com/paolorossi/1993068
http://binaryjs.com/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921790/best-approach-to-real-time-http-streaming-to-html5-video-client

Comment: Obrigado mesmo willian, o binary eu já tinha dado uma lida, mas os outros links vou ler com cuidado. Brigadão willian!

Comment: @User o Nodejs permite que você abra uma conexão socket (com plugin socket.io), o resto é javascript amigo, faça uma aplicação que converse no lado do cliente, e que envie solicitações de video, ou qualquer coisa para o server-side, processe as solicitações no servidor e devolva o resultado para o cliente que estiver ouvindo o socket seja 1 ou seja broadcast, simples assim ^^